# How do i check mysql database extension enable/disable on server in php?

Tags: mysql, database, php, php-ini

I am working on a PHP install script, and I need to check many server settings before installing applications there.

So, how do I check the mysql database extension if it is enabled/disabled on client's server using PHP?

And I also need to check following extensions `Encryption` , `Zip Archive` whether they are installed on the server or not.

Please suggest a way to check these settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute this:

```
extension_loaded('mysql');
```

If it returns `true`, then the extension is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you,

```
extension_loaded('zip')
```

check if the zip extension is loaded or not. this will check only one extension at a time..

Comment: To check Encryption: `extension_loaded('mcrypt');`